# Get appdata\local folder path in C# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am try to get `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local` folder path using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

in a C# Windows service, but it returns some other path

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local
```

Does any have any idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: does it occur when you deploy your app?

Comment: It's normal, since your service runs under the `Local System` account.

Comment: Took away the -1 someone set (without comment) - seems a reasonable question to me and a trap many might fall into.

Comment: @Wolf5370: it was me. I was prepared to flag it too, but I noticed your comment. I think the user just wants a specific user profile folder, not **any** profile folder. In my opinion what happens here is normal behavior and the requirements are exaggerated.

Answer (score 9):

Are you running the service under a user account? If not, the service will use its own profile as you see. If this service is "logged into" by a user, then you could pass the folder to the service and bypass local checking. Otherwise, try running the service under a user account (or create an account for it).

Comment: Let me change the question, I want to get this path "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local", so what "ServiceAccount" should I use for this? or how will i get this path in C# windows service.

Comment: When you say "username" do you mean a real user's folder or do you just want a folder for you application? As Coon said in his comments, if you want a specific user without them actively being logged on and passing that information, then it is a security risk and as such will be an issue. The Coon and I are both correct in what we say, but we are answering different questions, so you need to specify how your service is being used and what access it wants. Then maybe we can hep further.

Comment: username is the current user logged in.

Answer (score 5):

The AppData folder for each user is stored in the registry.

Using this path:

```
const string regKeyFolders = @"HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders";
const string regValueAppData = @"AppData";
```

Given a variable sid string containing the users sid, you can get their AppData path like this:

```
string path=Registry.GetValue(regKeyFolders.Replace("<SID>", sid), regValueAppData, null) as string;
```

Comment: Note that this registry key doesn't seem to be set for built-in users, such as `LocalSystem`

Comment: For those wondering how to get the SID of users from a local system account, check out this blog: https://www.softwaremeadows.com/posts/writing-to-current-users-registry-when/ You can get the SID of all logged-on users using that WindowsIdentityHelper class used in that blog. Also, this answer was extremely helpful and smart, I was so lucky I found this question, thank you so much @Derrick.