# Application data for specific user

Tags: c#, windows, directory

I'm trying to get Application data folder for specific user. As I'm running my application as NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM, I get

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
```

but I want to get

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
```

I'm using

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

I have no idea to do this, unless by getting username ant just inserting it in

```
C:\Users\%%\AppData\Roaming
```

But not everyone has one user.

Comment: I can give you an answer because I don't have an application that run in that context, but you could try to read the `Environment.UserName` and check if it is different from the user that runs the application. Just a starting point.

Comment: Application runs always as SYSTEM, because it's a service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get appdata\local folder path in C# windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201308/get-appdata-local-folder-path-in-c-sharp-windows-service)