# Service writing files in a different path

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path, windows-services

I have 1 form and 1 service that should be writting to the same location. 
So I added the following line in both.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "myFolder" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "log.txt");
```

the problem is that the form is writing the file in the right location but the service isn't. 
 The service is writing in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\myFolder\log.txt` and the form in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\myFolder\log.txt`.

I can't use the windows event logger and i got to handle some other files too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201308/get-appdata-local-folder-path-in-c-sharp-windows-service

Answer (score 2):

The user that runs the service is either `NETWORK SERVICE` or `LOCAL SERVICE`, instead of a real user account. Under those special accounts, `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` comes to the `systemprofile` directory.

So to fix that, you'll need to change the user the service runs under, or hard code/determine the correct user directory to use.

Answer (score 0):

Put the folder name in a config file. Or at least put the user's name, so you can build the folder name properly in the service.